# Merging multiple table data into single query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am looking for single query where, main table has customer id and other 2 tables use customer id as a primary key and it has its own customerNumber which is unique to that table. Please refer below table.

mainTable

```
       CustomerId  CustomerName
    ------------------------
        1           Ben         
        2           Robert       
        3           Paul
```

table2

```
    CustomerId customerNumbers filed1       field2  
    -----------------------------------------------------
       1           100          100        100@gmail.com
       1           101          101        101@gmail.com
```

table3

```
    CustomerId customerNumbers       filed1       field2  
    ------------------------------------------------------------
        1           1000              1000        1000@gmail.com
        1           1001              1001        1001@gmail.com
```

table4

```
    CustomerId customerNumbers       filed1       field2        field3  
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        1           1000              1000        1000@gmail.com  500
        1           1001              1001        1001@gmail.com  700
```

expected result from single query is

```
    {
      CustomerId: 1,
      customerName: "Ben",
      customerDetails:[
                      {
                        customerNumber:100,
                        field1:100,
                        field2:100@gmail.com
                      },
                      {
                        customerNumber:101,
                        field1:101,
                        field2:101@gmail.com
                      },
                      {
                        customerNumber:1000,
                        field1:1000,
                        field2:1000@gmail.com
                      },
                      {
                        customerNumber:1001,
                        field1:1001,
                        field2:1001@gmail.com
                      },
                      {
                        customerNumber:1000,
                        field1:1000,
                        field2:1000@gmail.com,
                        field3:500
                      },
                      {
                        customerNumber:1001,
                        field1:1001,
                        field2:1001@gmail.com,
                        field3:700
                      },
                   ]    
               }
    }
```

We can achieve using alias, but I have 9 different sub tables which will makes query big with 20 columns. Can we achieve this with single query?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Do you really want to generate something that looks a little bit like JSON, but isn't valid JSON?

Comment: Okay Thank you. yes like a JSON, Its just a sample, i need something similar to that

Comment: Which DB Are you using? The functions need to call are not the same

Comment: we are using postgresql

Comment: A fiddle could be useful. In this case you can use a custom datatype, build result with an aggregation and eventually cast as json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting table2..tableN rows to json should give you unified structure suitable for `union`. Then you aggregate those objects to json array with `json_agg`:

> ```
> create table mainTable(CustomerId int, CustomerName varchar);
> create table table2(CustomerId int, customerNumbers int, field1 int, field2 varchar);
> create table table3(CustomerId int, customerNumbers int, field1 int, field2 varchar, field3 int);
>
> insert into mainTable values(1, 'Ben'), (2, 'Robert'), (3,'Paul');
> insert into table2 values(1,100,100,'100@gmail.com'), (1,101,101,'101@gmail.com');
> insert into table3 values(1,1000,1000,'1000@gmail.com',500), (1,1001,1001,'1001@gmail.com',700);
> ```

> ```
> select 
>     json_build_object( 
>         'CustomerId', m.CustomerId, 
>         'customerName', m.CustomerName, 
>         'customerDetails', json_agg(t.js))
> from mainTable m
> join (
>     select CustomerId, row_to_json(a)::jsonb-'customerid' js from table2 a
>     union all 
>     select CustomerId, row_to_json(a)::jsonb-'customerid' js from table3 a
>     ) t on t.CustomerId = m.CustomerId
> group by m.CustomerId, m.CustomerName
> ```
>
> ```
> | json_build_object                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"CustomerId" : 1, "customerName" : "Ben", "customerDetails" : [{"field1": 100, "field2": "100@gmail.com", "customernumbers": 100}, {"field1": 101, "field2": "101@gmail.com", "customernumbers": 101}, {"field1": 1000, "field2": "1000@gmail.com", "field3": 500, "customernumbers": 1000}, {"field1": 1001, "field2": "1001@gmail.com", "field3": 700, "customernumbers": 1001}]} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=741963998e993a07e2ea27288dfc3ea1)*

Comment: There is bit change in the requirement, now I want to response with uneven columns. I had edited my question. please check for reference. Currently you can see table4 has "field4". Is it possible to achieve this way?

Comment: @user3335796, you can check if the edited code solves your problem